# Java regex for preserving currency symbols along with comma and dot if they are surrounded by numbers

Tags: java, regex, split

This is my input string

```
String inputString = "fff.fre def $fff$ £45112,662 $0.33445533 abc,def 12,34"
```

I tried below regex to split

```
String[] tokens = inputString.split("(?![$£](?=(\\d)*[.,]?(\\d)*))[\\p{Punct}\\s]");
```

but it is not preserving comma and dot if they are surrounded by numbers. Basically,I don't want to split by comma and dot if they are part of price value

Output I get is

```
token==>fff
token==>fre
token==>def
token==>$fff$
token==>£45112
token==>662
token==>$0
token==>33445533
token==>abc
token==>def
token==>12
token==>34
```

Expected output

```
token==>fff
token==>fre
token==>def
token==>$fff$
token==>£45112.662
token==>$0.33445533
token==>abc
token==>def
token==>12
token==>34
```

Comment: How about debugging it on something like [a regex debugger](https://www.debuggex.com/) ?

Comment: btw, not all currency characters are put before the number, e.g. 12€ would be common in Europe. Also not everyone uses `.` as decimal separator. Germany uses `5.312,50€` to mean `€5,312.50` for example. See `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `split`, you may use this simpler regex to get all the desired matches:

```bash
[$£]\w+[$£]?|[^\p{Punct}\h]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cNDbVz/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `[$£]`: Match `$` or `£`
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word chars
- `[$£]?`: Match optional `$` or `£`
- `|`: OR
- `[^\p{Punct}\h]+`: Match 1+ of any char that are not whitespace or punctuation

**Code:**

```
final String regex = "[$£]\\w+[$£]?|[^\\p{Punct}\\h]+";
final String string = "fff.fre def $fff$ £45112,662 $0.33445533 abc,def 12,34";
        
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println("token==>" + matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is working for given example. I wanted to split and convert into Set, that's why I had used split, however,I can use this as well to convert to Set.

Comment: It is not matching for strings like £45112-662 or £45112@662

Comment: It does match `£45112@662` as one match, do you want something different?

Comment: Sorry for the typo! What I meant was, £45112@662 should have been considered as separate token i.e. £45112 and 662, but it considers as one token.  May be instead of S+ we could use d+

Comment: ok try this regex: `[$£]\w+[$£]?|[^\p{Punct}\h]+`